# Rendering a partial from one controller to another below content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my views, I have `comments/_form.html.erb`, and there is another controller views for `post` `posts/show.html`. I want to render `comments/_form.html.erb` in `posts/show.html`, which shows an individual post and comments associated with that post, and it is all set and working fine.

I want to provide ability to comment and render that partial below these comments so that we can make new comment on the same `posts/show.html` page instead of navigating to `comments/new.html.erb` page. I am using nested resources like:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

In my `comments/new.html.erb`, I am doing this:

```
<%= form_for([:post, @comment]) do |f| %>
  ....
<% end %>
```

How should I render it in my `posts/show.html.erb` page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is the missing piece in your puzzle.  Essentially you'll do 3 things.

1. Make sure your form is using js to submit (remote)
2. Make sure your controller responds to js input
3. Create a js.erb file that will append each new comment

Implementation notes:
I would probably do something like this:

Add the form to the view, and add an element that wraps around the comments, in this case, I used ul#comments

```
# app/views/posts/show.html.erb
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Body:</strong>
  <%= @post.body %>
</p>

<br/>
<ul id="comments">
  <%= render @comments %>
</ul>
<%= form_for [@post, @new_comment], remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :body %>
  <%= f.submit  %>
<%end%>
```

Add the js response in the controller

```
# app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
def create
  @post = Post.find params[:post_id]
  @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
  @new_comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @comment.save
      format.html { redirect_to [@post, @comment], notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
      format.js 
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Then add a ujs file to make your changes on the fly (this does 2 things, adds a new comment and empties the form).

```
# app/views/comments/create.js.erb
$('#comments').append("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: '/comments/comment', locals: { comment: @comment } ) %>"); 
$('form.new_comment').find("input#comment_body").val('');
```

Also to note::

- I'm using `@new_comment` so there is no interference when you render a newly created comment
- You'll need to add `@new_comment` in 2 places, first in your posts show action and also in your comments create action

Comment: How do I get access to the comment variable?
Mine is named id and I tried: 
id, @id, params[:id], locals[:id]
but nothing works. 
Any ideas?

Comment: If you're passing id in the locals section of the partial render, then it's available as `id`   Nothing around it and no `@` because it's not an instance variable, its only local to the particular partial you've passed it to. (though I would always caution against using the naming convention of `id`) Since you said you tried that, you might need to post a new question with code samples so you can be helped further.